# How to run airflow scheduler as a daemon process?

Tags: google-compute-engine, scheduler, airflow

I am new to Airflow. I am trying to run airflow scheduler as a daemon process, but the process does not live for long. I have configured "LocalExecutor" in airflow.cfg file and ran the following command to start the scheduler.(I am using Google compute engine and accessing server via PuTTY)

```
airflow scheduler --daemon --num_runs=5 --log-file=/root/airflow/logs/scheduler.log
```

When I run this command, the airflow scheduler starts and I can see the airflow-scheduler.pid file in my airflow home folder, but the process does not live for long. When I close the PuTTY session and reconnect to the server, I cannot find the scheduler process. Am I missing something? How can I run the airflow scheduler as a daemon process?

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem.
My airflow scheduler did not keep running as a deamon process when I executed scheduler as deamon:

```
airflow scheduler -D
```

But the scheduler did work when I ran it normally. After I deleted the airflow-scheduler.err file and rerun the scheduler as a deamon process it started working:

```
rm airflow-scheduler.err
airflow scheduler -D
```

Comment: I also have had to delete airflow-scheduler.pid

Answer (score 5):

You can use systemd or upstart as described here:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/scripts/systemd
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/scripts/upstart

Here are the instructions just in case if links break in the future.

> The provided systemd files are tested on RedHat based systems. Copy (or link) them to /usr/lib/systemd/system
>   and copy the airflow.conf to /etc/tmpfiles.d/ or /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/. Copying airflow.conf ensures /run/airflow is
>   created with the right owner and permissions (0755 airflow airflow)
>
> You can then start the different servers by using systemctl start . Enabling services can be done by issuing

`systemctl enable [service]`

> By default the environment configuration points to /etc/sysconfig/airflow . You can copy the "airflow" file in this
>   directory and adjust it to your liking. Make sure to specify the SCHEDULER_RUNS variable.
>
> With some minor changes they probably work on other systemd systems.

You can modify provided below configuration files to reflect your environment

Content of /etc/sysconfig/airflow file

```
# This file is the environment file for Airflow. Put this file in /etc/sysconfig/airflow per default
# configuration of the systemd unit files.
#
# AIRFLOW_CONFIG=
# AIRFLOW_HOME=
#
# required setting, 0 sets it to unlimited. Scheduler will get restart after every X runs
SCHEDULER_RUNS=5
```

Content of /etc/tmpfiles.d/airflow.conf or /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/airflow.conf file

`D /run/airflow 0755 airflow airflow`

Content of /usr/lib/systemd/system/airflow-scheduler.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow scheduler daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/airflow scheduler -n ${SCHEDULER_RUNS}
KillMode=process
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: As the links may break in the future, it would be very useful for you to include the information that is relevant to answer to this question in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, cavpollo. I have added all the relevant information.

Answer (score 4):

`--num-runs=5` will make scheduler run task instances 5 times. You can remove that arguments to make scheduler long running.

Ideally you should run that scheduler under supervisor, so when the process crashed / stopped, it will rerun.

Comment: `Ideally you should run that scheduler under supervisor, so when..`; I guess `Restart=always` in the `[Service]` *description* does exactly that