# Why is the task inside my DAG not running?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have scheduled my airflow DAGs to run, every DAG has one task inside of them. When the DAGs run, the tasks inside them don't get executed.
[image]

Here's my code for the same ***(I am trying to SSH into an EC2 server and run a bash command)***:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['removed@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'start_date': datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='back_fill_reactivated_photo_dimension',
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval='55 * * * *',
          dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=120))

t1_bash = """
/usr/local/bin/dp/database_jobs/run_py.sh "backfill_photo_dim_reactivated.py"
"""

t1 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_conn_id='ssh_aws_ec2',
    task_id='backfill_photo_dim',
    command=t1_bash,
    dag=dag)
```

The Airflow UI shows the DAG to be in the running state but the actual task inside the DAG never runs, am I missing something in my code?
[image]

Also, is there a way to force run a DAG regardless of it's CRON schedule?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you do not have `scheduler` running.

Run `airflow scheduler -D` to turn it in a background. That should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

A task stuck in "scheduled" generally means you have no pool or no queue available.
Are you using local executor? if yes, is the scheduler running?

You can force run (or test) a task using the command line.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the airflow scheduler was running. I will look into that pool thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with you dag check your configurations.Can you share your cfg file

Comment: here you go: https://codeshare.io/anMVBY
just an FYI: I am using my own AWS RDS database to store all the airflow metadata.

Comment: what msg broker are you using(i.e rabbit mq)

Comment: is this issue for this dag or for all dags

Comment: can you change you executor to Local executor in cfg file and try if its works then there is configuration issue for sure

Comment: will do that, and will get back to you.

Comment: it worked, when I switched the executor to `Sequential` , now the problem is - the DAG only runs once, whenever I trigger `airflow scheduler` from the command line, why is that? why is it not following the cron schedule I specified in the code?

Comment: here you go: https://codeshare.io/2pERYD 
(this is the output, after I manually triggered `airflow scheduler`)


so, I have to manually trigger my airflow everytime I have to run a DAG, it's not picking up the CRON schedule. But it does pick up when I do `airflow scheduler`.

Do I have to use something like Supervisor so that airflow scheduler runs forever. 

Appreciate your help, Ravi.

Comment: and this is the output of my `airflow scheduler` which seems to be working fine: https://codeshare.io/5QL16m

Comment: do you think it might be related to this issue? I think I will have to add a fixed date to the `start_date` field instead of `datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714087/apache-airflow-scheduler-does-not-trigger-dag-at-schedule-time?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: just try to give some date in past and check whether its running or not

Comment: I just did, and also I followed this here for running Airflow webserver and scheduler in the Daemon state (As a background process):
`airflow scheduler -D` and `airflow webserver -D`
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476246/issues-running-airflow-scheduler-as-a-daemon-process

 may be it will help.

Comment: can you type command " ps -ef | grep airflow " on your terminal i want to check whether scheduler is running or not

Comment: there are so may schedulers running ..that not right... kill them all and start a fresh scheduler

Comment: is above issue resolved let me know if you need any help

Comment: really appreciate you checking up on this, Ravi, everything is running great now. So what I did, I ran Airflow scheduler and Air webserver in the Daemon state, you do that by doing this - `airflow scheduler -D` and 
`airflow webserver -D` so that way Airflow runs in the background forever and I am using `localExecutor` for running my DAGs